# Gradle: Adding publish task of submodule as dependency to another submodule

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

My project layout is like this

```
A
├── B
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── Example-0.0.1.jar
├── build.gradle
├── C
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── sample
│                       └── Hello.java
└── settings.gradle
```

Now, B uses maven-publish to publish Example-0.0.1.jar to local maven archives (i.e ~/.m2/repositories)

C is a java project. The Hello.java file uses the Example jar file.

I am using gradle 2.2 to build this project.
I have

```
$ cat A/build.gradle 
allprojects {
        repositories {
                mavenCentral()
                mavenLocal()
        }
}
```

and

```
$ cat A/settings.gradle 
include ':B'
include ':C'
```

and

```
$ cat A/B/build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
        publications {
                maven(MavenPublication) {
                        groupId 'com.example'
                        artifactId 'abc'
                        version '0.0.1'
                        artifact 'Example-0.0.1.jar'
                }
        }
}
```

and

```
$ cat A/C/build.gradle 
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
        compile project(':B')
        compile 'com.example:abc:0.0.1'
}
```

Now, whenever I run any gradle command, I get the following error:

```
$ gradle tasks
Execution failed for task ':tasks'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':C:compileJava'.
```

Is there any way such that task B:publishToMavenLocal be run before building of C in order to include the jar?

Comment: As far as I understood rather not. Projects are evaluated (build scripts) and then build. These are separate phases.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same issue.
Figured out a way to achieve this. I added following to parent build.gradle file and everything is now working as expected.

> project(':project-B').tasks.compileJava.dependsOn project(':project-A').tasks.install

So now when i am executing the build, artifacts of project-A is being installed to local repository and then project-B is able to take them from there. Good Luck!!